# unitTest wmi PerformanceCounter

Tags: c#, unit-testing, wmi

I created PerformanceCounter that count the total number of processed items.

```
PerformanceCounter pCo = new PerformanceCounter(CategoryName, CounterName, false);
...
pCo.Increment();
```

I want to run a test to check the output of the cuonter.

How can i read the data from WMI?

Answer (score 0):

There's another question about [unit testing WMI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44338/unit-testing-with-network-reliant-code) here on stackoverflow that might be of interest to you.

You could create mocks that would simulate data generated by performance counters.

I have a suggestion I know that goes against conventional thinking:  install and allow a performance counter to run as part of the unit test, test the data and during the unit test clean up, uninstall the performance counter.  I haven't done this explicitly performance counters but I have created unit tests that install/uninstall "something" as part of the test of it.